# library not work in nestjs useGlobalFilters with library

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have a problem with the following, I created a script to capture prism errors and standardize, but when I hosted it on npm and imported it into the project it simply doesn't work, note I can run it within the code but not through import.

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-exception-filter-prisma-nestjs

my code:

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
// import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './errors/PrismaError';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from 'http-exception-filter-prisma-nestjs';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
  app.enableShutdownHooks();
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from './database/prisma.service';
import { UsersModule } from './modules/users/users.module';
import { AuthModule } from './modules/auth/auth.module';
import { DealershipModule } from './modules/dealership/dealership.module';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from 'http-exception-filter-prisma-nestjs';
import { CustomErrorsHandleFilter } from './errors/CustomErrorsHandle';
// import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './errors/PrismaError';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, AuthModule, DealershipModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    PrismaService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: CustomErrorsHandleFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I created a file with the same code and it worked, however I would like to use the library to deal with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you running a local version of the lib but I'd suggest you to remove the hard dependencies on `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core`. Move them to peer dependencies instead.

[image]